# Can't connect Java Spring Boot Jasper Reports filling process to MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, jasper-reports

I am generating reports with Jasper Reports by using a Java Spring Boot application that uses Maven for dependencies. The code I have works for connecting to MariaDB but I am now trying to get it to use MongoDB as the report connection and it is throwing errors that I am struggling to debug. The code will compile and run but throws an error at runtime.

I should probably also mention that I am successfully connecting to this Mongo database elsewhere in the application but I am using Spring data (spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb or in other words MongoRepository) in those cases.

I have shortened stack traces to the part that I think is most likely to be relevant because of character limits and the spam filter. Let me know if you want the full stack trace and I will try to post it.

Here is the error that is getting thrown:

```
com.smartapi.utils.Utils$MsgException: jasper.error
        ...[ommitted]...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Integer com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getThreadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier()'
        ...[omitted]...
```

Here is the relevant code for the report filling/generating process (when I am trying to connect to mongo)

```
    public static void processJasperReportFromDbToPdf(ReportRq rq, OutputStream os)
    {
        rq.params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_CLASS_LOADER, subreportClassloader);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try (
            Connection mongoDBConnection = new MongoDbConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database?authSource=admin", null, null);
        )
        {
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rq.report, rq.params, mongoDBConnection);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, os);
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            Utils.throwMessage(t, "jasper.error", rq.reportName);
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        logger.info("Created: " + rq.reportName + ". Time=" + time + "msec");
    }
```

Here is the same code but for connecting to MariaDB. This code works perfectly, I am actively generating reports with this code.

```
    public static void processJasperReportFromDbToPdf(ReportRq rq, OutputStream os)
    {
        rq.params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_CLASS_LOADER, subreportClassloader);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try (
            Connection mariaDBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/my_database?user=my_database_user&password=my_password");
        )
        {
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rq.report, rq.params, mariaDBConnection);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, os);
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            Utils.throwMessage(t, "jasper.error", rq.reportName);
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        logger.info("Created: " + rq.reportName + ". Time=" + time + "msec");
    }
```

Here are the parts of my POM file that I think are relevant.

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jfrog.io</id>
            <name>jfrog.io</name>
            <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/jrs-ce-addons-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- JASPER REPORTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>6.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jaspersoft.connectors.mongodb/js-mongodb-datasource -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jaspersoft.connectors.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-mongodb-datasource</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

### Here are some things I have tried already:

- I tried with and without "mongodb-jdbc" included in my dependencies
- I tried a few older versions of "js-mongodb-datasource" (2.0.8, 2.0.5, 2.0.2) but they produced similar errors (different method not found each time, specifically, ConnectionString.getCredentialList(), then this for both of the next ones com.mongodb.Bytes cannot access its superclass org.bson.BSON)
- I tried replacing the connection line as follows but got a different error

```
        // this is called in main before "SpringApplication.run( MyApplication.class, args );" and does not cause an exception
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not register the com.mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver");
        }


        // this replaces the connection in the try, catch of the code above
        Connection mongoDBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database?authSource=admin");
```

this is the new error

```
com.smartapi.utils.Utils$MsgException: jasper.error
        ...[omitted]...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database?authSource=admin
        ...[omitted]...
```

- I have tried downgrading Jasper to the version upon which "js-mongodb-datasource" is dependant (6.8.1) that generates this different error. Googling this error indicates I need to upgrade my Jasper version.

```
com.smartapi.utils.Utils$MsgException: zip.error
        ...[omitted]...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from InputStream.
        ...[omitted]...
```

Comment: If you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, do you see any difference/improvement?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No change. Each connection type produces the same error as described above.

Comment: Okay after manually stepping through the code I think I found the issue but I don't know how to actually properly resolve it.


It seems that when "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb" is used with "js-mongodb-datasource" in a project the code from the later tries to use versions of classes from the former. Specifically from mongodb-driver-core:jar:4.0.5 (dependency of "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb") rather than mongo-java-driver:jar:3.10.2 (dependency of "js-mongodb-datasource").


If I create a project with everything except "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb" everything works.